# I am not quite sure how to complete this question, may someone please guide me in the right direction?

Tags: calculus

Here is the question:  Find the minimum amount of road required to connect 4 towns each of which is located at the vertex of a square. Assume the shortest distance between any two towns is 1 km.

Answer (score 1):

The information they give us implies the square is of length 1.

There are several possibilities we can try in search for the best. Also, we will assume that we do not have to have roads directly connecting the 4 towns.

If we cover all the sides of the square we use $4$km of road. But removing one of the roads keeps the towns connected, so that would take $3$km.

On the other hand, if we were to put roads on the two diagonals and create a big intersection in the middle, we would be using $2\sqrt{2} $km, which is just below $3$km.

I cannot think of a better roading but also I am not sure of how to formally prove this is the best configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration (roads in red).

[image]